# Create an array and check against it

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, numbers

I am not sure of how to do this, but what I want to do it create an array and be able to add new items to this array. Since the items are supposed to be a random number, when a new instance is created I would like it to be checked against the rest of the array and be sure that the number it has generated is not already in the array. How would I accomplish something like this?

---

I looked at Šime Vidas's answer and it seems to work, but I tried to shorten it to

```
var arr = []; 

function add(a) {
var n =  ~~(Math.random() * 100);
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if ( a[i] === n) { a.push(n) }
}

}

for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
    add(arr)
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += arr;
```

and I don't understand why this wouldn't work. It does pretty much the same thing, correct?

Comment: The deleted answer proposed to use objects as datastrucure. Why was it deleted? Seems a good idea to me. It avoids looping the array.

Comment: I'd agree with @Felix. As long as the original order isn't important and an actual Array isn't a requirement, using an Object for this would be extremely simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var arr = []; 

function add(a) {
    var n =  ~~(Math.random() * 1000);
    !is(a, n) && a.push(n);
}

function is(a, n) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if ( a[i] === n ) { return true; }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The `add` function creates a random integer number between 0 and 1000, and adds it to the array.
The `is` function checks whether the `n` number is somewhere inside the `a` array.

***Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/kHhMp/2/

***Demo 2:*** http://jsfiddle.net/kHhMp/3/

(Demo 2 shows that a number will only be added to the array if it's not already in it.)

---

btw

```
!is(a, n) && a.push(n);
```

is a short form of this:

```
if ( is(a, n) == false ) { a.push(n); }
```

The number is added to the array only if `is(a, n)` returns false.

---

**UPDATE**

```
var arr = []; 

function add(a) {
    var n =  ~~(Math.random() * 1000),
        ok = true;

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if ( a[i] === n ) { ok = false; }
    }

    ok && a.push(n);
}
```

Comment: i can't tell if the OP wants the number to be actually randomly generated or if he is getting the numbers elsewhere. also, this is crazy hard to read if you have to come back to this code later.

Comment: @Jason What exactly is hard to read? The `is` function is as straight-forward as it gets. The `add` function uses `~~` and `&&` which are hard to understand only if you don't understand them (obviously). If you do understand them, you can read trough the function pretty fast I believe.

Comment: @Jason Yea, I think the OP is getting the numbers elsewhere. We'll see what he says...

Comment: No, you are correct, they are random numbers, the (Math.random() * 1000) is correct.

Comment: What exactly is the `~~` for?

Comment: @Sean It's pretty much the same as Math.floor(). It returns the integer component of a number. I stumbled upon this technique just yesterday `:)`

Comment: Very cool. Could you please explain to me exactly what the `!is(a, n) && a.push(n);` line does? What is the `!is()` mean and why would you put `&& a.push(n)` instead of simply putting `a.push(n)` on it's own line?

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind checking my question again real quick, I posted an update to it.

Comment: @Sean I should have thought of combining the two functions into one myself. I've updated my answer with the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you enjoy fast code and you have many items in your array, you should use an Object rather than an Array.

Instead of doing `var my_array=[]; my_array.push(my_number)`, use `var my_object = {}; my_object[my_number] = true` to add items in your structure.

With that approach, you can easily check if a new number is already in there with an `if (my_object[my_number]) { /* already there */ } else { /* not there yet */ }`

Once you're done, you can extract the list of numbers as an array by either using `var keys = Object.keys(my_object)`, or if that's not available, `var keys=[],i=0;for (keys[i++] in my_object);`, more or less.

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = []

array[0] = 'Item'

array[0] === undefined
# returns false

array[1] === undefined
# returns true
```

Comment: How is `in` performance-wise on arrays? I could imagine that an object would be better.

Comment: @Felix: no idea. I’m thinking it might be a terrible idea to use it anyway — I think it tests for object properties, rather than just array indices.

Comment: @Felix `in` looks up properties and will traverse the prototype chain it's slow and possible buggy. @Paul You Should use strict equals `===` otherwise `(array[0] = null) == undefined` will be `true`.

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel: True, somehow I thought `in` would work differently on arrays (but of course it doesn't). I guess I had `indexOf` in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest, most cross-browser way is to iterate over the array using a loop:

```
var arr = [];

function addNum(num) {
    for (i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        if ( arr[i] === num ) { return false; }
    }
    arr.push(num);
}
```

Be sure to get the length of the array before you run the loop so the length property isn't constantly checked.

Answer (score 1):

You may extend the built in `Array` object for your needs.

```
Array.prototype.pushUnique = function(value) {
  var len = this.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(this[i]===value) return;
  }
  this.push(value);
}

var uniques = new Array();
uniques.pushUnique(1);
uniques.pushUnique(2);
uniques.pushUnique(1);
// array will contain only 1 and 2
```

Comment: `var i` or `i` leaks into global scope.